# firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider is undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, ecmascript-6

This is how I import firebase into the project:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import firestore from 'firebase/firestore'
import auth from 'firebase/auth'

/*
Config */
const FIREBASE_CONFIG = {
   ...
}

/*
Get a Firestore instance */
export const firebaseInstance = firebase.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG)
```

Later I would just:
`import { firebaseInstance } from 'database'` whenever it's needed and have  to access `singup`, `login` and other available API methods like for example:

`firebaseInstance.auth().fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email)`

However when I am trying 
`firebaseInstance.auth.EmailAuthProvider` as defined in the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.html#credential) it's simply not available and returns `undefined`

Can somebody please suggest what can be missing?

P.S: I've tried `firebaseInstance.auth().EmailAuthProvider` however after researching in github thread how other people do it, I believe that is not the thing :)

Comment: Documentation says it's static method, so it doesn't make sense to call it on instance? You can find it under `firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider`

Comment: @MiroslavPapírník you are right, thank you for the help, if you want create an answer I will approve it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation says it's static method, so it doesn't make sense to call it on instance? You can find it under `firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider`